# Oracle + Sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

How can I connect my sencha app to oracle db.

Any ideas??

I am trying to make a customer book with 2 columns.
values will be shown in the mobile app.

Comment: Sencha is not backend, its frontend. Oracle db needs a backend.

Answer (score 1):

Ok @Shaleen,

1. Can you connect to database with Java or C# or with whatever you want.
2. The information you get from the database you can convert to JSON.
3. With Sencha can you get JSON file with information available.

**Hope these helps. :)**

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

**Steps:-**

1. Get the values from the form panel ( assuming you use it) and call an `Ext.Ajax.request()` on form submission.
2. Provide the url of the php path ( in case you're using PHP at the backend) and make all connection inside PHP file to db, retrieve the values using `$_POST[]` and insert them into the db.

Comment: can you please give me url of some detailed example as i have never done backend work...i usually work on front end with json..